# ASP.NET Core app on IIS very slow startup

Tags: asp.net, iis, asp.net-core

We are deploying our new .NET Core Wep Api through TeamCity and Octopus, it runs on Kestrel behind IIS. Everything is fine except that the first request takes about 2 minutes. That is, the first request after deploy and the first request after restarting the site on IIS.

To publish the app we use

```
dnvm use 1.0.0-rc1-update1 -a x64
dnu publish --configuration release --runtime active --no-source --include-symbols
```

Older apps on the same IIS Instance take about 15sec to respond to the first request. 
Our .NET Core app responds after about 15 seconds when running it purely on Kestrel from the same actual code that is deployed to IIS.

What is happening for the remaining 1m45s - why is it taking so long?

How can we go about to debug this?

**Update:**

As it turns out, IIS is unable to shut down the Kestrel process (dnx.exe) gracefully. It crashes with the following error:

```
Unhandled exception at 0x00000000776E298A (ntdll.dll) in w3wp.exe: 0xC000070A: Status 0x (parameters: 0xFFFFFFFFC0000008, 0x0000000000000324, 0x000000000167D930, 0x0000000000277520, 0x000007FEE60388F4).
```

If I terminate the dnx.exe process manually and then restart the site it starts up quite fast, so my theory is that the Octopus deploy step somehow encounters the same exception and IIS has to wait for the host process to time out before it spawns a new working process.

How can I make IIS shut down the dnx process gracefully? How can I get a more understandable exception from IIS?

Comment: You might use tracing such as failed request tracing on IIS side and ETW tracing on ASP.NET side to check how the time is consumed.

Answer (score 0):

The cause of the problem was that IIS was unable to gracefully stop the dnx process running Kestrel, and had to wait for it to timeout in order to get a working one running.

To work around this we added a PowerShell script to stop the dnx process manually as the first step of the Octopus Deploy process:

```
Stop-Process -processname dnx -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue -Force
```

As to why IIS is unable to gracefully terminate the worker process and how to fix that I still have no idea.